A problem in using Cauchy Integral Theorem when the function is only assumed to be continuous on the boundary (Rudin's RCA 16.8)
16.8 Theorem
Suppose $\Omega$ is a region, $L$ is a straight line or a circular arc,
$\Omega - L$ is the union of two regions $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, $f$ is continuous in $\Omega$,
and $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega_1$ and in $\Omega_2$. Then $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$.
Proof. The use of linear fractional transformations shows that the general case follows if we prove the theorem for straight lines $L$. By Morera's theorem, it is enough to show that the integral of $f$ over the boundary $\partial \Delta$ is $0$ for every triangle $\Delta$ in $\Omega$. The Cauchy theorem implies that the integral of $f$ vanishes over every closed path $\gamma$ in $\Delta \cap \Omega_1$ or in $\Delta \cap \Omega_2$.

The continuity of $f$ shows that this is still true if part of
$\gamma$ is in $L$, and the integral over $\partial \Delta$ is the sum
of at most two terms of this sort

My question:
How can I deduce that "this is still true"? This is Rudin's original Cauchy Theorem.

In my opinion, I have to handle the following cases:

The central problem that I have to handle is the line lying on the $L$ for both of them.
How can I deduce the result by applying uniform continuity?

Can you apply uniform continuity on a compact subset?

@TedShifrin Do you mean change the order of limit and integral on the path approximating the desired path?

Yes, I believe that is what I mean.

Part I. (Completely Revised Posting) After a bit of reflection I realized that  this generalization of Cauchy's Theorem can be proved quite economically as follows.
To show $\oint_T f(z)dz=0$ pick an interior point within $T$, call it the origin, and consider the family of dilated functions $ f_a(z)= f(z/a)$ where  the real factor $a\to 1^+$. Then $f(az)$ is analytic on the dilated triangle  $aT$ that contains $T$. Thus $\oint_T f_a(z) dz =0$ by the standard Cauchy Theorem.  Finally, argue that since $f(z)$ is continuous on a neighborhood of $T$,  $f_a(z)\to f(z)$ uniformly on $T$, then interchange integration and limits to deduce that $0=\oint_T f_a(z) dz \to \oint_T f(z) dz=0$.
Part II. For the sake of completeness, I'll retain my original posting below.
I claim that we don't need to explicitly invoke uniform continuity of $f$, (or in fact any uniform convergence principles). We just need the patience to re-examine the usual proof of the FTC, which works perfectly well under the given slightly weaker hypothesis.
The goal is to prove this claim:
Theorem. If $f(z)$ is continuous in an open disk $D$ and analytic on either side of a line segment $L$ in $D$, then $f(z)$ is analytic across $L$.
Proof of Theorem.
To show that $f(z)$ is analytic across $L$,  observe that it suffices to show that $f(z)=F'(z)$ for some function $F(z)$ that is analytic across $L$.
Take the line $L$ to be horizontal and place the origin at the center of  an open disk $D$.
Define a complex-valued function $F(z) =\int_P f(s)ds$ in $D$ by specifying that the path $P$  is a two-step zig-zag path  from the origin to $z$: a horizontal leg  along $L$, followed always by the vertical leg. This is an unambiguous choice of path, so $F(z)$ is well-defined in $D$.
Thus to prove the Theorem it suffices to prove the following:
Proposition. ( The extended FTC) This  function $F(z)$ is complex-differentiable and its derivative is $F'(z)= f(z)$ at every $z\in D$.
Two cases: (i) $z$ is off $L$, or (ii) $z$ is on $L$.
Case (i). If $z\notin L$, (e.g. $z$ lies above $L$) then  we choose $h$ so small that $z+h$ is also above $L$. Consider $\Delta F =F(z+h)-F(z)$. It can be expressed as the difference of two partially-overlapping path integrals. After cancelling the overlapping legs, that difference reduces to integration over a tall but narrow U-shaped path whose base is a small segment on $L$ of width $\Delta x = Re(h)$. Now we proceed to deform $U$ to a nearby path $\tilde U$ that avoids the line $L$. The path-difference  $U-\tilde U$ can be taken to be a square-shaped closed  loop $S$. That is, $S$ is  a very tiny square of size $\Delta x$ whose base rests on $L$ and $\tilde U$ lies  above $L$.
Write $\Delta F(h)= \Delta_1 (h)+ \Delta_2(h) $
where $\Delta_1(h)=\int_{\tilde U} f(s) ds$ and $\Delta_2(h)= \oint_S f(s) ds $.
Since $f(s)$ is analytic above $L$, Cauchy's Theorem can be used
to replace the integral taken over $\tilde U$ by a straight-line segment from $z$ to $z+h$ ( a  crucial trick). Then the usual proof of the FTC can be used to show that  the complex derivative of $\Delta_1(h)$ is $f(z)$. (The essential techniques in that  proof of the FTC are recapitulated when we consider $\Delta _2$ below.)
It remains to show that the derivative of $\Delta_2(h)$ is zero. Take $s_0=Re(z)$, a fixed vertex of the square on $L$. By continuity of $f(s)$ in $D$, we can write $f(s)= f(s_0)+ \epsilon(s)$, a constant plus a small variable term. Note that the integral over $S$ of the constant term $f(s_0)$ is of course zero. The integral of the small variable term  over the small path can be handled using the usual $M-L$ estimation procedure; that is  $$|\oint_C f(s) ds|\leq ML$$ where
$M=Max(|f(s)|: s\in C\}$ and $L=$Length of the path $C$.
Deduce that  $\Delta_2(h)=\oint_S \epsilon (s) ds =o(|h|)$.
Case (ii). This is an easier degenerate case of (i) involving only two small legs. Deal with it just as $\Delta_2(h)$ above.
Footnote. The preceding proof is easily adapted to prove the more general result that if $f$ is continuous on  an open disk $D$, and if $C$ is a smooth curve in $D$ whose complement splits $D$ into two open sets on which $f$ is analytic, then $f$ is analytic on all of $D$.
(By smooth we mean that the parametrized curve is continuously differentiable and its derivative is never zero.)
Sketch of proof.
It suffices to prove that $f$ is analytic across every sufficiently small arc of $C$. Just localize to a very small disk centered at a point on $C$, take that point as the origin, and rotate $C$ so that it's tangent line is horizontal. Parametrize the curve as a function of $x$: written as $y= h(x)$. Then define $F(z)$ as the integral of $f$ over two legs, the first being an arc of $C$ from the origin to the point whose real coordinate is $Re(z)$, and whose second leg is the vertical segment  where $Re(z)$ is constant.
In this setting $\Delta F$ can be written as a path integral over a tall narrow $U$-shaped path whose narrow base is a small arc of $C$. The proof then proceeds just as above.

Thanks a lot for your patient and pedagogical idea. I still wonder how can I get the quick solution by uniform continuity rigorously

what is the usual M-L elimination
